# Did anyone implement Asymmetric cryptographic algorithm in Contiki OS specially in Rime stack.?

Tags: security, elliptic-curve, contiki, dtls

I m trying to implement Elliptic Curve cryptography algorithm such as ECDH in Contiki Rime Stack in multihop executing in Cooja simulator but first I need to know..whether they implemented any security algorithm in Contiki Rime stack or not..I already tried the contiki-tls-dtls-master which is not working.I think its not working for skymote..I tried several codes but still not working..the normal FILE is working as we use CFS in contiki OS..So pls help me with this question.Thank you in advanced.